# How to send UDP datagrams from different applications but from the same SOURCE port?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, udp

We have two apps

1. The first one is the UDP server and it listens and responds with the SOURCE port (12345)
2. The second app is an only responds and no listen, we need to respond with a specified source port (12345)

How to achieve this?

We are trying to use many scenarios but:

1. We can't bind the socket in the second app because it used in the first one
2. We can't use SO_REUSEPORT in the second app for bind, because this app starts getting UDP data instead of the first app
3. We can use IPC from the second app to the first app and then send as usual UDP (sendto) but this is a very huge workaround

Comment: This isn't (IMO) a programming problem, but rather a design, analysis or even requirement problem. What is the original requirement that leads to multiple applications needing to use the same port?

Comment: You can't share a port like that between processes, at least not easily. You need a proxy in the middle that handles traffic and then you can use IPC or additional UDP networking to route those to the correct destination. Alternatively you could try and spoof it using a raw socket, but I'm not sure how successful that approach will be.

Comment: I don't want to share port, I just want to send UDP datagrams with the same SOURCE port from different apps.

Comment: The original requirement is the following: all UDP datagrams from both apps should be sent from the same SOURCE port 12345. Currently, we have such situation: the first app sends from SOURCE port 12345 because it used 'bind', and the second app sends from a random SOURCE port because of kernel behavior.

Comment: In Linux 3.9+ you could try SO_REUSEPORT in *both apps*, and it might just work. I do not know the details.

Comment: https://medium.com/uckey/so-reuseport-addr-2-2-how-packets-forwarded-to-multiple-sockets-ce4b83cd0fd2 this suggests that it isn't easy anyway.

Comment: What is the *actual* requirements of your system? Who told you that both apps needs to use the same port? Where did this requirement come from? Perhaps you need to take some time to discuss with your technical lead and project manager about this requirement, or maybe even talk directly to the customer.

Comment: Idea: use IPC (unix sockets) to send the socket from one app to the other, so that both apps use the same socket, instead of using two different sockets with the same port.

Comment: We are using IPC right now, yes, the only one solution but we are searching something more. Maybe we can use RAW socket and send UDP with the needed source port.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336811/send-udp-from-specific-port-without-bind

Comment: The same question but about Python
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055266/sending-a-udp-packet-with-source-port-but-without-binding?rq=1
I think RAW sockets is only one way to go

Comment: Raw sockets is almost never the correct solution. It will add much more complexity to your program, making it harder to maintain. Not to mention that you will duplicate a lot of work that already exist in the system, which is almost never good. As I stressed before, this is a *requirement problem*, something which you *must* bring up within the project group. Even if it's a school assignment or project, this needs to be brought up. And if it's just your own little pet-project, then you need to take a few steps back, check your *actual* requirements, and possibly redo your analysis and design.

Comment: We are making a hardware-based project and it's very important that UDP packet source port and destination port will be the same. Currently, we have two processes and both of them sending UDP packets with different payload inside. This is completely normally and acceptable from the design perspective. The only one issue it's source port from second process.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be for the server (1st process) to send the socket file descriptor to the sender (2nd process), so that they both share the same kernel UDP socket file description (rather then 2 sockets bound to the same port), but only one process (the server) reads from it.

You can pass a file descriptor to another process using either `fork` or `fork-exec` or [Unix domain sockets `SCM_RIGHTS` ancillary messages](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html).

Comment: Yes, thank you for the hint, we have found this approach too but it looks also complicated . Thanks

Comment: @Dmitry If your server uses an I/O event loop, then it should be easy to also make it listen on a Unix socket in addition to that UDP socket. That's just trivial socket plumbing, tedious, but not rocket science.

Comment: Yeep, This is how it works today. We have the UDP server with 'any' address listening and the second app sends UDP packets to the localhost for UDP server with a special signature, destination address, and data inside it, we are getting it and resend to the specified dest address from the server. But, we are worried about performance due to the additional layer.

Comment: @Dmitry What I described requires no forwarding/resending of UDP messages.

Comment: We have two different processes so we need IPC to inject I/O events from one process to another somehow.